# Get the list of unused load balancers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am trying to list the unused load balancers(elb).. I am trying the below code and it throws an error

'Attribute Error': 'str' object has no attribute 'describe_instance_health()'

```
import boto3

elb = boto3.client('elb')

allElbs = elb.describe_load_balancers()
print (allElbs)
for lb in allElbs:
    instances = lb.describe_instance_health()
    if len(instances)==0:
        print (lb)
    for instanceState in instances:
        if  instanceState.state == 'OutOfService':
            print (lb)
```

Please help me solve this..
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiYDk.jpg)

Updated Code:

```
import boto3

elb = boto3.client('elb')

allElbs = elb.describe_load_balancers()
#print (allElbs)
for lb in allElbs['LoadBalancerDescriptions']:
    #instances = elb.describe_instance_health(lb['LoadBalancerName'])
    #instances = elb.describe_instance_health(['LoadBalancerName'])
    instances = elb.describe_instance_health(LoadBalancerName=lb['LoadBalancerName'])

    if len(instances)==0:
        print (lb)
    for instanceState in instances:
        if  instanceState == 'OutOfService':
            print (lb)
```

Comment: You should be doing: `elb.describe_instance_health(LoadBalancerName=lb['LoadBalancerName'])`

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 Now, its not printing any result eventhough I have Load Balancer with no instances.

Answer (score 3):

Below. The call to `describe_load_balancers()` return a dict. Inside the dict you can find the list of the lb's. See [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elb.html#ElasticLoadBalancing.Client.describe_load_balancers) and [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elb.html#ElasticLoadBalancing.Client.describe_instance_health).

```
import boto3


def filter_lbs():
    """ return a list of lb's that has no instances or in state OutOfService"""
    result = []
    elb = boto3.client('elb')
    lbs = elb.describe_load_balancers()
    for lb in lbs['LoadBalancerDescriptions']:
        instances = elb.describe_instance_health(LoadBalancerName=lb['LoadBalancerName'])['InstanceStates']
        if not instances:
            result.append(lb['LoadBalancerName'])
            continue
        for instance in instances:
            if instance['State'] == 'OutOfService':
                result.append(lb['LoadBalancerName'])
                continue
    return result
```

Comment: @mytech please simply include the error text (it's small), not a link to an image.

Comment: @jarmod"  %s() only accepts keyword arguments. "%py_operation_name)
TypeError : describe_instance_health() only accepts keyword arguments.

Comment: I think the code fix was supplied by krishna_mee2004 earlier. You need to supply keyword arguments, not positional arguments. You need to understand the distinction in order to be able to work in Python.

Comment: @jarmod Thank You. Now, its not printing any result eventhough I have Load Balancer with no instances.

Comment: @mytech You've printed out all the ELBs in the current region. Is the result what you expected? Now, for each ELB, print out all of the instances returned from describe_instance_health(). Is that list what you expected? Specifically, are the count of instances and the individual state of the instances what you expected? Try to reconcile these facts with your supposition that there should be 'ELBs that are unused'.

Comment: I have updated my code in the original post. I just want the list of ELB that doesn't have instances or instances in out of service..

Comment: @mytech Does it work for you or you still need support? If its not working please describe what is wrong.

Comment: @balderman Its not working yet as expected. I just want to print the unused ELB(ELB with no instances/instances in Out of Service).

Comment: @mytech I have updated the code and created the function 'filter_lbs'. Try it.

Comment: @balderman The result is empty. It doesn't print anything.. Please advise.

Comment: Do you have code that actually call the function 'filter_lbs'?

Comment: @balderman %s() only accepts keyword arguments. "%py_operation_name) TypeError : describe_instance_health() only accepts keyword arguments.

Comment: @balderman Thanks for your help, still doesn't print anything..  The result is empty

Comment: @mytech Add few debug prints. print the name of each lb (before the instances line). How many lb's do you have

Comment: Are you looking at the correct region? In what region do you have the "idle" ELBs? It seems like you are either running this script in an EC2 instance or from your local machine with a profile set. If running using local credentials (via profile), what's the default region defined? If you are running this script in an EC2 instance, what's the region where your EC2 instance is running? Ensure that regions match.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 I am trying the correct region and the region match. But its not showing any result.

Comment: Did you add the debug print to the function?

Comment: @balderman Yes itis printing all ELBs when I give print(lbs).. But no result in the filter..

Comment: Is it possible that all lbs have instances and none of them is out of service? Add the Len of the instances and the state to the debug prints.